# How to select an Instance from a List based on a Value?

Tags: python, list, class

I have a lists of instances of a class that holds two variables: value and expectation.

```
import random 

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.expectation = random.random()

my_list = []
for i in range(1, 11):
    my_list.append(MyClass(i))
```

I now want to get the value of the instance with the max expectation. How do I get this?

Comment: Please don't use "list" as a variable name.

Comment: @ArindamRoychowdhury You're right!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oneliner:

```
max(my_list, key=lambda x:x.expectation).value
```

Answer (score 1):

```
my_list = []
max_obj = max(my_list,key=lambda myClass:myclass.expectation)
max_value = max_obj.value
```

Answer (score 0):

The max expectation:

```
max([obj.expectation for obj in mylist])
```

The Instances with max expectations:

```
ll = list(filter(lambda x:x.expectation == max([obj.expectation for obj in my_list]), my_list))
```

Comment: This returns max of expectations